# Can't find node.js binary

Tags: c#

I was learning how to program in c# by using visual studio code. I just opened my computer one day to learn more but it kept on saying: "Can't find Node.js binary "node": path does not exist. Make sure Node.js is installed and in your PATH, or set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json". I don't know what has happened I have very little programming language.

Operating System: macOS Big Sur

Comment: I don't know why you need `node.js` for C#, maybe the problem is something else. But to solve this problem, you have to add a new path to `system variable`. Path like this: C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting a nodejs error if you are learning C#?
Anyway you need to reinstall node js and when you click through the installation there will be a checkbox saying "add ro PATH" or something similar. You need to check that box

Comment: I never did install node.js. Im just learing C#. It just happened all of a sudden I don't know why though

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE for C#, C++ and NodeJs maybe you started a NodeJs Project?